# Passing Scala Object/companion object as parametric type

Tags: scala, generics

I'd like to have a method like this:

```
def foo[O] = O(1,2,3)
```

Where "O" would be a scala object with a defined apply method. With my signature, I got the "**Cannot resolve symbol O**" error.

Calling foo passing a "Set" or a "List" as parameter gives me the "**Type XXX takes type parameter**". What's the way to pass a companion object as a parametric type?

How can I create this method?

Comment: Because such a declaration doesnt make any sense. What u trying to do?

Comment: I know that it does not make any sense, that's why I'm asking :)
I'd like something like that:

Comment: foo[Seq] = Seq(1,2,3)
foo[List] = List(1,2,3)

And so On

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the apply method (the thing that is called when you say `List(1, 2, 3)`) as an argument instead:

```
def foo[O](apply: (Int*) => O): O = apply(1, 2, 3)

println(foo(List.apply))
->  
List(1, 2, 3)
```

Or, if you really want to pass in the companion object of a Collection class (though this is less versatile than the above solution), you can pass in `GenericCompanion` objects such as the `List` companion:

```
def foo[O[T] <: GenTraversable[T]](comp: GenericCompanion[O]): O[Int] = comp(1, 2, 3)

println(foo(List))
->  
List(1, 2, 3)
```

Note that this requires higher-kinded types to be enabled in the compiler.

Or, rather than passing in the companion object, you can use an implicit CanBuildFrom (these are defined for you for all collections):

```
def foo[O[_]](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[O[_], Int, O[_]]): O[Int] = 
  bf().++=(Seq(1, 2, 3)).result().asInstanceOf[O[Int]]

println(foo[List])
->  
List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I supposed there was a way to use just the notation foo[List]  but I see that's not possible

Comment: @Stefano It is actually possible, see my edit, but it actually still passes an (implicit) parameter

Comment: Thank you @Vitruvius, you're amazing :)

Answer (score -1):

The type of a companion object is referenced using the `.type` property.  If you want to create a list of companion objects, the following would work:

```
object MyObject {
  def apply():Unit = {
    println("Hello, world")
  }
}

val c = List[MyObject.type](MyObject, MyObject)
c.foreach(_.apply())
```

Comment: I don't think they want to create a list of companion objects.

Comment: There is only one object of type `MyObject.type` - it makes no sense to create a list of it.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for "Calling foo passing a "Set" or a "List" as parameter gives me the "Type XXX takes type parameter". What's the way to pass a companion object as a parametric type?"  I gave a way of creating that list or set